# 'sudo apt-get update' always re-updates by force?

Tags: 12.04, apt, official-repositories

I have a fresh install of 12.04.

If I understand correctly, `sudo apt-get update` is supposed to update everything the first time it's run, and then only update repositories which have changed since the last update, right?

However, this command seems to be updating all repositories every time I run it. That is, even if I run the command twice back-to-back, the second command will re-update all repositories again by force.

This is disturbing to me, since I have a slow (512 kbps) Internet connection.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What's the second command?

Comment: The second command is 'sudo apt-get update'. This was the first command too. That's why I said 'if I run the command **twice** back-to-back'.

Comment: This also happening in my fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04. Anyone has answer?